# How to change the EKCalendar's EKSourceType?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to change the EKCalendar's EKSourceType ?

```
EKEventStore *eventStore;
```

I am printing this value using `NSlog`.in console `eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.type` is always `0`

So `0` means the `EKSourceType` is `EKSourceTypeLocal`
But I need to fetch the events of **Exchange Mail** which is added in the native iPad Calendar. So is there any way to change the `EKSourceType` , if we cannot change sourceType, then how can we fetch the new Events added in native calendar of iPad? which is added in `EKSourceTypeExchange`

Comment: Hope helps you:  http://oleb.net/blog/2012/05/creating-and-deleting-calendars-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

EventKit does not allow you to add, modify, or remove EKSource instances. The default calendar for new events may not always be set to a calendar in the source you expect—it could be the user's personal calendar, for example.

It sounds like you're trying to find the Exchange source on this device, which you could do as follows.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = // instantiate event store and request access
EKSource *exchangeSource = nil;

for (EKSource *source in [eventStore sources]) {
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeExchange) {
        exchangeSource = source;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that it's possible to have multiple sources of any given type, so you may want to ask the user which calendar to use.

Comment: Hey - what is the source type for "OTHER". I can see 'Birthdays' & 'Events Found in Apps' calendars added to it? Can I add more events here programmatically?